# Hyperledger Fabric - New MSP affiliation error - access denied: channel [ ] creator org [ ]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using hyperledger fabric.

I have added a new affiliation to the msp of org1 of my network.

Then, I created a new user that belongs to "org1.myAffiliation" msp.

Unfortunately, when I try to submit a transaction I run into this error:

```
access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [org1.myAffiliation]
```

Do you have any idea what cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this error before, for me it was because the org had not joined the channel.

Can you confirm if you face it for same reason?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, the org has already joined the channel. I have only added a new affiliation to the existing msp. But it seems that the channel doesn't recognize the new affiliation.

Comment: If by affiliation you mean new hostname like from `org1.example.com` to `org1.newexample.com` then you need to append the new MSP to the channel config, you'd have to do more research to figure out what changes will be done to it though. I'd suggest asking on [rockerchat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric) for more help.